# Error 404 on IIS after updating API

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis

So I had an API with this structure:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/AppMananciais")]
public class AppMananciaisController : ApiController
{
   // GET api/<controller>
   [AcceptVerbs("Get")]
   [Route("DadoDia/{_data}")]
   public object DadoDia(DateTime _data)
   {
       /*some code*/
   }
```

That I used to call like this?
http://myurl.com/api/AppMananciais/DadoDia/2018-01-01

We then developed an update for it and included an optional parameter for the API version

```
// GET api/<controller>
[AcceptVerbs("Get")]
[Route("DadoDia/{_data}/{api_version?}")]
public object DadoDia(DateTime _data, int api_version = 1)
{
    /*some code*/
}
```

So both these calls were supposed to work:

http://myurl.com/api/AppMananciais/DadoDia/2018-01-01
http://myurl.com/api/AppMananciais/DadoDia/2018-01-01/2

We tested locally, on Visual Studio, then published on development server, testing server and acceptance test server, working as expected in all of them.

When we finally published into production server it didn't work as expected. The old way to call the API is working fine

http://myurl.com/api/AppMananciais/DadoDia/2018-01-01

And from the results we can tell it is indeed running the updated version.

But the new way to call the API returns error 404
http://myurl.com/api/AppMananciais/DadoDia/2018-01-01/2

All servers are running the same version of IIS (8.5.9600.16384)

Their Web.config are identical, save for a Key/Value pair that indicates where to fetch de data. Tests indicates the data source is working fine and understands the new syntax with the api version parameter.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.6" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="apiIntranet" value="http://datasource:1059/" />
  </appSettings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
  </configuration>
```

After some research I tried to include the following line in the Web.config, but didn't solve the issue:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

Any tip on what else should I look for in order to make the API work as expect and verified in every other server it was tested?